# How can I login a client to a 3rd party site with basic access authentication from django

Tags: django, basic-authentication

What I want is for the user to click a link on my site and be redirected to a 3rd party app that uses basic http authentication. It's my understanding that basic authentication works by the client adding an Authentication header to every request.

How do I tell the clients browser, from django, to redirect to a different link with the authentication header filled out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't force a redirection with custom headers. You can force custom headers in javascript code for ajax only ($.ajax lets you add custom headers) - but it has nothing to do with a normal redirection. The solution you expect perhaps has a solution with OAuth (it is based on cookies) but you cannot: "redirect to a different link with the authentication header filled"

Comment: I was afraid of that. Needed confirmation. Thanks.

Comment: Think Oauth is the most clean solution for what you are trying to do. Is the 3rd party something like Google or Facebook!?